# Why doesn't this mod_rewrite 301 redirect work?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Other RewriteRules work, so I've replaced those, and put this one first. Mangling it deliberately returns a 500 error, so I'm confident that my syntax is wrong, rather than my configuration.

I have redesigned a site that used to have URLs like:

```
/product_view.asp?product_id=123&images_id=456
```

My new site has URLs like:

```
/shop/product/123
```

(where the two `123`s are the same as I've kept the same database)

My RewriteRule is:

```
RewriteRule ^product_view.asp\?product_id=([0-9]+).*$ /shop/product/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but nothing happens – no errors, no 500s, just nothing.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: perhaps it's caused by the missing `images_id` in the rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule` refers only path, that does not include `QUERY_STRING`. Find `product_id` from `QUERY_STRING` with `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product_id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^product_view\.asp$ /shop/product/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Grouped part in `RewriteCond` can be referred as `%1`. It can be used in `RewriteRule`.

If `?` is placed at the end of *substitution* part of `RewriteRule`, `QUERY_STRING` will be discarded. (You can use `QSD` flag instead if your Apache version is 2.4 or later.)  It is not always needed, but perhaps you don't like such ugly URL as `/shop/product/123?product_id=123&images_id=456`.

Check [mod_rewrite document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for detail.

Comment: I didn't know that! That's actually completely changed my understanding of how mod_rewrite works – thanks!